# Entity Framework Core - Call A Populate Extension Method Inside Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I will explain my issue using an example.
Lets say I have this following classes and methods (I created them only for this example)

```js
  public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public Subject Expertise { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LicenseId{ get; set; }
        public License License { get; set; }

    }
    public class License
    {
        public string LicsenseType;
    }

    public static IQueryable<Subject> PopulateWithTeacherAndLicense(this IQueryable<Subject> subjects)
    {

        return subjects
            .Include(c => c.Teacher)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.License);
        
    }
```

Now lets assume I want to select all students with all their subject,teacher and license. In order to do so, I want to use my PopulateWithTeacherAndLicense. I want the query to look something like:

```js
db.Students.Include(s => s.Expertise.PopulateWithTeacherAndLicense())
```

And not have to do Include(s=>s.Expertise).TheInclude(s => s.Teacher)...

Comment: .. and this is not working out for you? What issues do you have?

Comment: I receive this error: The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty

Comment: if you use your return type in the calling statement, it will look like this:

db.Students.Include(s => s.Expertise.subjects.Include(c => c.Teacher).ThenInclude(p => p.License));
Which I don't think is the operation you are intended to make, or am I way off?

Comment: The example that I brought was just a simple example to explain my problem.
The general question is how I can use a set of includes and then include statements  that I already wrapped inside as an extension method for an entity. So for example, If I created an extension method that populates all Subject graph, I want to be able to use it when I want to select the student with his full graph (without the need to repeat all the Include and ThenInclude statements). I hope I succeeded to explain myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension method for **Student** collection itself

```
public static IQueryable<Student> IncludeExpertise(this IQueryable<Student> students)
{
    return students
        .Include(s => s.Expertise)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.Teacher)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.License);

}
```

Comment: Yes, but if the the object graph is big it feels very wrong the copy all the code again